# SQL: user variable increment for each rows

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, case, increment

EDIT : my question is not clear, so I've reformulated it here : [Order sql result by occurrence of a set of keywords in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573270/sql-case-when-then-1)

I'm improving my search system for my website. I'm trying to use and increment variables in sql request, like that...

```
SET @titlematch = 0;
SELECT *,
CASE 
    when title like '%apple%' then (SET @titlematch = @titlematch+1)
    when title like '%orange%' then (SET @titlematch = @titlematch+1)
    when title like '%other_keyword_searched%' then (SET @titlematch = @titlematch+1)
    (...)
END,
(...)
FROM pages  
(...)
ORDER by @titlematch desc
```

In fact, titlematch should be incremented each time that a keyword is in the title. If there's "apple" and "orange" in the title, titlematch should be equal to 2.
But actually, it doesn't work...

(sorry for my english)

Comment: have you tried removing `SET` in case statement like this `CASE WHEN..THEN (@titlematch = @titlematch+1)` , also can you provide the error you are getting.

Comment: @Maxime R.: titlematch variable does always increment?

Comment: @snyder there's no error, but titlematch isn't incremented

Comment: @joetaras yes, always

Comment: why can't you use `COUNT` with condition `LIKE '%apple% OR '%orange%' OR '%other_keyword_searched%'`

Comment: @snyder you think it could increment titlematch each time that a condition is true, with count() ? how do you do that ?

Comment: You can select those rows in a `subquery` using `LIKE '%apple% OR '%orange%' OR '%other_keyword_searched%'` and then you can use `COUNT(*)` in `outer query` to get the no. of rows.

Comment: @snyder but I don't want the number of rows with a title 'like' the search keywords, I wan't to calculate the relevance of the title of each rows

Answer (score 0):

I think it fails because it must handle all the data,if title like someWordYouDontAcccountFor it will fail.You must account for all possible cases or use else.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment (Yes, always), I rewrite your query in this way:

```
SELECT *, (select count(*) from pages p2 where p1.field_date < p2.field_date) as pos
(...)
FROM pages p1
(...)
ORDER by (select count(*) from pages p2 where p1.field_date < p2.field_date) desc
```

In this way you count every rows before the actual (I've based my count on ipotetic field_date but if you want you can change your condition), so you have an incremental value for each row, and finally, I add this condition in order by clause.

Tell me if it's OK